# Offsetwidth by a new HTML Document

Tags: html, dom, offsetwidth

I want to create a new html document with javascript. There in the body i want create a div (display: inline) and in there a p tag. Then i put in the p tag (innerHTML) a String (titleTagString). Now i want know, which is offsetwidth the div has. The chrome console say 0 ...
Where is the failure?
Thanks!

```html
function titleTagTester(titleTagString) {
  //Create new document
  newDoc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('titleTagTester.html');
  //Create var body from document
  var body = newDoc.getElementsByTagName('body');
  
  //Create div element with style and add to body of document  
  newDoc.body.innerHTML += '<div style="width:600px" display="inline" id="divId"></div>';
  
  //Create p element with style and add to div of body of document  
  newDoc.getElementById('divId').innerHTML += '<p style="color:#1a0dab" "font-family:arial" font-size:18px;">' + titleTagString + '</p>';
  
  //getwidth of div
  return newDoc.getElementById("divId").offsetWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a HTML document with the script embedded within it such that the script manipulates the same document DOM:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>temp</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Domething</h1>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function titleTagTester(titleTagString) {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
  
  //Create div element with style and add to body of document  
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div style="width:600px" display="inline" id="divId"></div>';
  
  //Create p element with style and add to div of body of document  
  document.getElementById('divId').innerHTML += '<p style="color:#1a0dab" "font-family:arial" font-size:18px;">' + titleTagString + '</p>';
  
  //getwidth of div
  return document.getElementById("divId").offsetWidth;
}
console.log(titleTagTester('temp'))
</script>
</html>
```

For this web document, the console says **600**. This is not a good answer to your question since the intention is to create a new document and obtain the required offset from that document. However, the `createHTMLDocument` in your case doesn't seem to work and is found out by printing the value of `newDoc.readyState`, which turns out to be uninitialized, and this in turn is responsible for the offsetwidth value as `0`. One way to correct this is to call the function with an  onload event handler instead of calling the function directly within the script tag (Ex. `<body onload="titleTagTester('tempString')">`).